# Change IP of IIS7 Bindings in C#

Tags: c#, iis-7

I have an IIS7 web server that runs loads of sites each with multiple bindings. Each site uses host headers AND their own IP.

Using C# I need to change the IP on all bindings to 0.0.0.0 so they listen on all the IPs.

My current code doesn't add the new bindings but clears the old ones. Any ides what I'm doing wrong?

My Code:

```
using (ServerManager iisServerManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            foreach (Site site in iisServerManager.Sites)
            {
                List<Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding> bindings = new List<Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding>();

                foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding binding in site.Bindings)
                {
                    String protocol = binding.Protocol;

                    String hostHeader = binding.Host;

                    String ipAddress = "0.0.0.0";

                    Int32 port = binding.EndPoint.Port;

                    String bind = ipAddress + ":" + port + ":" + hostHeader;

                    binding.BindingInformation = bind;

                    bindings.Add(binding);
                }

                //Clear existing site bindings
                site.Bindings.Clear();

                Int32 bindingCount = site.Bindings.Count();

                foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding binding in bindings)
                {
                    site.Bindings.Add(binding);

                    bindingCount = site.Bindings.Count();
                }

                bindingCount = site.Bindings.Count();

                iisServerManager.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  Are you getting an exception or does nothing actually change in IIS?

Comment: It clears the bindings completely and doesn't save the newly added ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to remove and then re-add the same bindings.  You can just modify them in place and then commit your changes.  Also, you want to use the ip address of '*' instead of '0.0.0.0' when you want to listen on all ip addresses.

This worked for me...

```
using (ServerManager iisServerManager = new ServerManager())
{
    foreach (Site site in iisServerManager.Sites)
    {
        foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
        {
            string ipAddress = "*";
            int port = binding.EndPoint.Port;
            string hostHeader = binding.Host;

            binding.BindingInformation = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", ipAddress, port, hostHeader);
        }

        iisServerManager.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did actually try updating the binding in the foreach loop, but that didn't work. I wonder if it was the 0.0.0.0 that caused that or something else.... THANKS!